# I got this this error >> Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, components, rendering

I want to render Modal componen if data.alarmMode === EMERGENCY, however, I am not able to rendering anything and getting this error. I have tried to fix this problem but I am not able to fix this problem. I don't know why react cannot render Modal componenet.

```
 return (

                <Modal key={hash} hash={hash} data={alarmData[hash]} onClickAlarmOff={onClickAlarmOff} clockMode={clockMode} onClickCloseModal={onClickCloseModal} />
              )
```

in case

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CurrentTimeBox from './CurrentTimeBox';
import AlarmList from './AlarmList';
import AddAlarm from './AddAlarm';
import styles from './ClockBox.module.css';
import ModalEvent from '../containers/ModalEvent';
import { EMERGENCY, NIGHT } from '../constants';
import Modal from '../components/Modal';
import ClockModeBox from './ClockModeBox';
const ClockBox = ({ timeString, onClickCloseModal, makeModalvisible, currentTime, clockMode, modal, alarmData, onClickAlarmOn, onClickAlarmOff, ClockModeFunctionLists }) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.ClockBox}>
      <CurrentTimeBox currentTime={currentTime} />
      <ClockModeBox ClockModeFunctionLists={ClockModeFunctionLists} clockMode={clockMode}/>
      <div className={styles.AlarmLists}>
        {Object.keys(alarmData).length > 1 && alarmData.dataLists.map((hash) =>{
            const data = alarmData[hash]
          return (
            <AlarmList key={hash} hash={hash} data={data} onClickAlarmOn={onClickAlarmOn} onClickAlarmOff={onClickAlarmOff}/>
          )
        })
        }
      </div>
      <AddAlarm />
      {timeString.length > 0 && Object.keys(alarmData).length > 1 ? alarmData.dataLists.map((hash) => {
        const data = alarmData[hash]
        if (data.time === timeString && data.on) {
          if (clockMode === NIGHT) {
            if (data.alarmMode === EMERGENCY) {
              makeModalvisible();
              return (

                <Modal key={hash} hash={hash} data={alarmData[hash]} onClickAlarmOff={onClickAlarmOff} clockMode={clockMode} onClickCloseModal={onClickCloseModal} />
              )   
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          }

          makeModalvisible();
          // if (modal) {
            return (
              <Modal key={hash} hash={hash} data={alarmData[hash]} onClickAlarmOff={onClickAlarmOff} clockMode={clockMode} onClickCloseModal={onClickCloseModal} />
            )
          // }
        }
      }) : null
      }
    </div>
  )

};

export default ClockBox;
```

updated code

```
  return (
    <div className={styles.ClockBox}>
      <CurrentTimeBox currentTime={currentTime} />
      <ClockModeBox ClockModeFunctionLists={ClockModeFunctionLists} clockMode={clockMode}/>
      <div className={styles.AlarmLists}>
        {Object.keys(alarmData).length > 1 && alarmData.dataLists.map((hash) =>{
            const data = alarmData[hash]
          return (
            <AlarmList key={hash} hash={hash} data={data} onClickAlarmOn={onClickAlarmOn} onClickAlarmOff={onClickAlarmOff}/>
          )
        })
        }
      </div>
      <AddAlarm />
      {timeString.length > 0 && Object.keys(alarmData).length > 1 ? alarmData.dataLists.map((hash) => {
        const data = alarmData[hash]
        if (data.time === timeString && data.on) {
          debugger;
          if (clockMode === NIGHT) {
            if (data.alarmMode === EMERGENCY) {
              makeModalvisible();
              return (

                <Modal key={hash} hash={hash} data={alarmData[hash]} onClickAlarmOff={onClickAlarmOff} clockMode={clockMode} onClickCloseModal={onClickCloseModal} />
              )   
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          }

          makeModalvisible();
          // if (modal) {
            return (
              <Modal key={hash} hash={hash} data={alarmData[hash]} onClickAlarmOff={onClickAlarmOff} clockMode={clockMode} onClickCloseModal={onClickCloseModal} />
            )
          // }
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }) : null
      }
    </div>
  )
```

modal component

```
import React from 'react';
import { VIBRATION, NORMAL, NIGHT } from '../constants';
import styles from "./Modal.module.css";

const Modal = ({ onClickCloseModal, data, clockMode, hash, onClickAlarmOff }) => {

  const SOUND_EFFECT = 'https://pp.netclipart.com/pp/s/35-354079_jpg-transparent-library-hotel-front-desk-service-bell.png';
  const VIBRATION_EFFECT = 'https://st2.depositphotos.com/4520249/7558/v/950/depositphotos_75586693-stock-illustration-vibration-mode-phone-icon.jpg';
  let imgComponent = null;
  switch(clockMode) {
    case NORMAL:
      imgComponent = <img src={SOUND_EFFECT} />
      break;
    case VIBRATION:
      imgComponent = <img width="200px" height="200px" src={VIBRATION_EFFECT} />
      break;
    default:
      return;
  }


  return (
    <div className={styles.Modal} >
      <div className={styles.ModalOverLay}></div>
        <div className={styles.ModalContent}>
          {imgComponent}
          <p>{data.label}</p>
          <button className={styles.CloseButton} onClick={() => {
            onClickCloseModal();
            onClickAlarmOff(hash);
            console.log(33333)
          }}>close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Modal;
```

If the clockMode is not 'emergency the component do render Modal component correctly. However, what I want to do is render Modal component in case  if (data.alarmMode === EMERGENCY)

I don't know why it cannot render in this condition even if I used return statement.

update

```
const modalOn = () => ({ type: MODAL_ON });
makeModalvisible: () => dispatch(modalOn())
```

there was no problem with mpodalOn, I checked modal status was changed
I debugged and debugger went inside of **if (data.alarmMode === EMERGENCY)**
the problem is when ClockBox component can't render Modal component....
if if I used return statement

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be because you do not have an else statement after the following if statement: `if (data.time === timeString && data.on)`.
So when this requirement is not met, React will not know what to render.

Comment: I added else statement and return statement but it didn't work as well....

Comment: Could you update the code in your post? And could you also post the content of the Modal component?

Comment: Could you also add the function definition for the makeModalvisible() method?

Comment: Ok, I don't really see what could be going wrong then. Except the fact that you are calling the makeModalvisible() function inside the render of your component. Maybe you could try changing your makeModalvisible() function to the following: makeModalvisible: () => { dispatch(modalOn()); return null; }

Comment: Alright, let me know if you have any more questions! If my answer was sufficient, don't forget to upvote my answer :)